# AngularJS $http.get don`t get data from json file

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I have next code in the controller

```
app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('db.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phone = data;
    });
});
```

this is JSON file:

```
{
    "title1" : "first title",
    "title2" : "second title",
    "title3" : "third title",
}
```

and then I try to print the data like this:

```
<h1>{{ db.title1 }}</h1>
```

but in the browser I see nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using {{ phone.title1 }} instead ?

Comment: yes, now its work! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed first problem but there is another one
this is in json file

```
"nameArr" : [
    {
        "title": "title",
        "image": "images/img.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "title",
        "image": "images/img1.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "title",
        "image": "images/img2.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "title",
        "image": "images/img3.png"
    }
]
```

and ng-repeat in html like this

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="items in nameArr">
    <img ng-src="{{ items.image }}">
    <h1>{{ items.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

and again don`t show nothing

Answer (score 0):

Two things: 1) the object you reference in the template should be declared right off, not in the callback, and 2) the data coming back is going to be a string, you will need to use [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) or JSON.parse to parse it into an object.

```
 $scope.phone = {};
 app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('db.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phone = angular.fromJson(data);
    });
```

Also, in your template, you cannot get at this inside db, because you put it on phone:

```
<h1>{{ phone.title1 }}</h1>
```